# Is the entire Universe the same age?

Tags: cosmology

Is all of the visible Universe exactly the same age everywhere? What about the Universe beyond what we can see?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ben Hocking is right that the Universe we observe is not the same age everywhere: the further away we look, the younger things are, simply because the light from faraway objects takes time to reach us.

But you may be wondering about more than that: what if we could remove those light-travel-time delays and consider the Universe as it is *now*, as opposed to the way we *see* it (with greater delays for more distant objects)? Would it all be the same age in that case?

That turns out to be a more subtle question than you might think, because of relativity. Relativity says, among other things, that different choices of reference frame lead to different notions of time -- things that are simultaneous in one reference frame are not simultaneous in another. When you consider what a distant object is like *now*, you have to be careful to specify what reference frame you're talking about, because different frames lead to different "nows."

At each point in spacetime, there is a reference frame that seems like the "most natural" one to use, namely the one in which the expansion of the Universe looks roughly the same in all directions. Cosmologists tend to use that reference frame to define and synchronize their clocks. That is, the time coordinate at any point in spacetime is, by definition, the amount of time that would have elapsed according to an observer who'd been at rest in that reference frame since the Big Bang. That time coordinate is often called "cosmic time."

If you use cosmic time as your time coordinate, then it is true that, at any fixed moment of time, all points in the Universe have the same age. But it's true pretty much because of the way we defined our time coordinate, so this is kind of a vacuous statement!

**Update:** Based on the comments, I realize I should have explained some things explicitly. I'm considering here "cosmological" effects, meaning I'm ignoring things that are due to small-scale inhomogeneities and thinking about large scales, on which the Universe is approximately homogeneous. If, for instance, you hang around near the horizon of a black hole, you'll age at a different rate from someone else. Even if you avoid such extreme cases, small-scale variations in the gravitational potential will lead to small-amplitude age variations. In fact, the definition of cosmic time only really makes sense in the approximation where we're willing to average over small-scale inhomogeneities. If you're not willing to do that, then different prescriptions for synchronizing your clocks, no one of which is obviously more natural than another, will lead to small differences in ages of things.

Comment: @Ted Bunn: Nice addition. I question your last paragraph, though. Wouldn't general relativistic effects make that not true, since time flows slower in a gravitational field? (As an extreme case, consider the adventures of an observer near the event horizon of a black hole who can manage to watch the universe age billions of years while mere minutes elapse for himself.)

Comment: +1 for the "vacuous statement" statement, I think another question is: from those "young" galaxies or "parts of universe", we could be seen as "young" too for being far away? vacuous statement too I think

Comment: Your definition of Cosmic Time, "looks roughly the same in all directions", seemed too vague, so I looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_time. That seems different, but supposing it's what you mean I suppose the condition of homogeneity is not satisfied on small scales, and it seems a little too convenient for it to be precisely satisfied everywhere on large scales. It seems possible that there might be different time-like foliations that might be "equally" Cosmic for a given nontrivial evolving matter distribution.

Comment: @Ben Hocking -- I probably should've been more explicit here. I was considering only "large-scale" or "cosmological" effects. You're quite right that small-scale, local differences will still lead to differences in age.

Comment: @HDE -- If an observer "now" (i.e., at the present cosmic time) is observing us from a distant galaxy, he/she/it will indeed see us looking "young."

Comment: @Peter Morgan -- the two definitions are equivalent, for a homogeneous Universe, although that's not necessarily obvious. It's true that on small scales the Universe is not homogeneous. Taking those inhomogeneities into account, there isn't an obvious "best" definition of cosmic time. Different prescriptions for defining the time coordinate in an inhomogeneous Universe lead to different coordinate systems, also known as different gauges. As long as inhomogeneities are small (as they seem to be, at least when small-scale features are averaged over), gauge differences are small.

Comment: @Ted Bunn: Yes, thanks, I was in fact asking about age without light travel delays, and your answer makes sense (it's pretty much the one I gave when asked), even if it is a bit (inherently) unsatisfying. Could you elaborate a bit on what "looks roughly the same in all directions" means? Is that equivalent to "has the same value of the inflation field" (not that I'm clear on what that means either). Rgds+Thx!

Comment: Operationally, you can imagine defining the "local rest frame" at any point in spacetime to be the frame in which the total momentum of all of the matter in a large sphere is zero. The rest frame you find will depend on the size of the sphere, but in an approximately homogeneous Universe it will settle down to an asymptotic value before the radius gets too big. (Once the sphere becomes comparable in size to the Hubble length, you run into problems anyway.) [Continued in next comment ...]

Comment: If you use just photons instead of massive particles in the above, then you're essentially finding the frame in which the microwave background radiation looks as nearly isotropic as possible (since most photons in the Universe are CMB photons). To be more specific, this prescription is equivalent to saying that the rest frame is the one in which the observed CMB has no dipole moment. Since the CMB dipole is accurately measured, this is the one that's most useful in practice for finding our local rest frame.

Comment: So the only practical measure of "what time it is" that applies on a cosmic scale for all observers in all locations and speeds is the degree of "expandedness" observable (on however large a scale is necessary to produce a clear measurement). Am I right in feeling that that produces a somewhat circular answer to my original question, since the reference point for such a clock is the (single, shared) Big Bang; in fact it has to be for the measure to be useful.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. In a sense, it is circular (I used the word "vacuous," but I meant the same idea) to say that all parts of the Universe are the same age. But here are some statements that aren't vacuous (and appear to be at least approximately true): 1. At every point in spacetime, there is a local reference frame in which things look roughly the same in all directions. 2. If we define the age at any point to be the elapsed time since the Big Bang, as measured by a clock at rest in this frame, then points with the same age also are also at the same density.

Comment: @Ted Bunn: Yes, that's what I was trying to say. Are there additional assumptions needed to arrive at these two statements though? E.g. I gather that (1) requires some assumption of homogeneity (on suitably large scales). I also wonder how a the "clock" (2) in the rest frame measures time. Won't it be measuring time by referring to density? Thx+Rgds!

Comment: It does assume homogeneity (as usual, when averaged over large scales). As to how the clock measures time: it doesn't matter! Devise any sort of clock you like, as long as it works in gravity-free vacuum. Put it in a small shielded box, and let it tick away from the moment of the Big Bang until the moment you want to measure the time. An atomic clock measuring the vibrations of a cesium atom would be a good choice, for instance.

Comment: @Ted Bunn: Can we be sure that (a) such a clock would always run at the same rate everywhere and (b) that it would be synchronized with expansion? I.e., can we assume that such a clock would tell same "expansion time" everywhere? Put another way: why not use expansion as the clock?

Comment: The assertion that different kinds of clock run at the "correct" rate is a content-ful, non-vacuous assertion about the world. It's essentially the principle of equivalence: a clock in a sealed box won't "notice" the expansion around it and will run at the correct rate. Of course, I can't check this assertion directly as applied to the early Universe, but people can and do check it in lots of other circumstances, and it seems to be a good assumption. [More in next comment.]

Comment: You could if you prefer *define* time in terms of the density of the Universe. Then the statement that any given type of clock correctly tracks the time as defined in this way becomes a content-ful, in principle testable assertion. That way of formulating the theory feels less natural to me. Our model of the Universe is based on general relativity, in which there is a notion of (proper) time independent of any particular solution to the equations, so defining time in a way that relies on properties of a particular spacetime feels like a bad idea. Anyway, it's not what people usually do.

Comment: Your *small-scale inhomogeneities* on which the eigen-age of objects can deviate may very well be quite large. We do know that inhomogeneities in the large-scale structure are $\sim$Gpc in size (sizes of galaxy super clusters and larges voids). In large voids, the eigen-age may be 18Gyrs as opposed to 13.7. -- **essentially your answer is wrong**. The models used by cosmologists to interpret data from Planck and similar missions all *assume* a perfectly homogeneous universe, which is inconsistent with the facts that 1) we observe significant inhomogeneities and 2) GR is nonlinear.

Answer (score 1):

No, the further away we look, the younger the Universe becomes. That's why we're able to see [galaxies that were forming when the Universe was approximately a half billion years old](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/01/27/science/space/27galaxy.html). Although it's *possible* there is an unknown portion of the Universe beyond what we can see, we currently have no reason to believe such a region exists. Rather, the boundaries of what we can see are dictated by [when light decoupled from matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_Big_Bang#Dark_ages).